# Pentaho Data Integration what is Update Partition Plugin

Tags: plugins, integration, pentaho, partition

In Pentaho Data Integration what is Update Partition Plugin?
[image]

I tried PDI tool version pdi-ce-9.3.0.0-428 and I'm getting the error for Update Partition Plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using PDI with files created in the past or by another person. That file was created using a step that was not available in the stock software, but added when adding a plugin to the PDI installation.

I've googled for a plugin going by that name, but I haven't found it with a quick search. Maybe the people providing the file (transformation or job) can be able to help you to install that plugin.